# ionic framework googleplay services error after instaling fcm plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, firebase-cloud-messaging

after i instaled the fcm in my ion app i  cant build the app for android(i dint tried to build for ios). the error says:

:processDebugGoogleServices
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.+, but version 9.0.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.
:processDebugGoogleServices
FAILED

i searched for where is declared the version of play-services but i failed, also i searched on the google but the topics i found were all old.
I dont know how to fix it,anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not solve the problem using the past plugins, after searching a lot and finding little about the rpoblema decides to change the plugin FCM by the plugin firebase (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase/) the implementation of both is almost the but the second one does not present any version problems and also allows some more functions

Answer (score 0):

You may have conflict plugins which uses different versions of the Play Services library.
There are Cordova plugins to help on that.

Try installing this plugin:

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release

If the issue still not resolved, you may need to install the sister plugins aswell 
https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release